# how should I bind this through a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've the code something like below:

```
function foo(){
  $('div').each(function(){
   //here $(this) refers to selected div
  });
});
```

Now, when I call foo in setInterval the `$(this)` won't be referring to the div of each() method:

```
setInterval(function(){
  foo();
},5000);
```

I tried with bind():

```
setInterval(function(){
  foo();
}.bind(this),5000); //or bind(document.querySelectorAll('div'))
```

I'm incorrectly referring to the div `$(this)` really. What should I do?

---

Here's a proof that I'm getting undefined:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Upvote to counter spammer

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/bj1zkx9n/

Comment: Your code has a syntax error. `foo` shouldn't close with `})`. Check your console for errors because your code works otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, that's just mistake while asking a question but in my code there is no such mistake. And this is referring to undefined

Comment: I'm getting undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the code inside the `each` callback to have access to whatever value `this` has when the `setInterval` call is made, your code has two problems.

The first is that you're not `bind`ing `foo` itself. The code

```
setInterval(function(){
  foo();
}.bind(this),5000);
```

successfully binds `this` to the anonymous function `function() { foo(); }`. This anonymous function then makes a direct call to `foo`, which (in non-strict mode) sets the `this` for the call to the global object `window` or `global`, as happens with any direct function call.

You need to explicitly pass on the anonymous function's `this` to the `foo` call inside the anonymous function with `call` or `apply`:

```
setInterval(function(){
  foo.call(this);
}.bind(this),5000);
```

Now that `foo` has the right `this`, you need to make that `this` value accessible inside of the `each` callback. For that, you can consult [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback), which will instruct you to store the outer `this` in another variable. You simply store `this` inside another variable and use that variable instead of `this` inside the inner callback:

```
function foo() {
  var outer_this_from_foo = this;

  $('.rsContent').each(function(){
    //here $(this) refers to selected div
    //but outer_this_from_foo refers to the `this` value just outside this callback

    var fI = $('>.img-responsive', outer_this_from_foo);
    // instead of $('>.img-responsive', this)

  });
};
```

Comment: @C-linkNepal Edited; you can use `call`. To do it with `bind`, with `foo.bind(this)()` but that's needlessly resource-intensive (and not idiomatic); `foo.call(this)` will do the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still getting undefined.

Comment: It's saying: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Comment: Sounds like `foo` isn't defined in your anonymous function for some reason. Consider how your code differs from mine (which works fine) and you'll probably see wherever your code is going wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/x1s0ta42/

Comment: Is there anything mistake [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bj1zkx9n/3/)

Comment: @C-linkNepal Yes, you're doing `foo().call(this)` instead of `foo.call(this)`. You're directly running `foo` and then trying to `call` the *result value* of `foo`, not `foo` itself.

Comment: OH! but still getting undefined (i'm surprised)

Comment: you may check edited question for a proof that I'm getting undefined...

Comment: @C-linkNepal You haven't even used the information in my answer yet. You've skipped the entire second step of storing the `this` in another variable within `foo`; there is no `outer_this_from_foo = this` or similar in your code.

Comment: please contribute giving a correct code of mine, I'm not understanding.

Comment: could you please modify my code that would work (just in a fiddle), I'm still getting undefind.

Comment: @C-linkNepal I've made another edit to the answer; if this is not clear enough, I do not understand how I can make it any more explicit; I'm sorry. Perhaps the explanation in the link I've provided will be clearer?

Comment: I just tried that way too, but still getting undefined...

Comment: And I'm getting undefined is not a function : [with this code](http://jsfiddle.net/bj1zkx9n/6/)

Comment: In firefox : TypeError: n.createDocumentFragment is not a function

Comment: Your `this` is `window`, which isn't a valid thing to `prepend` to, nor is it a valid context for a jQuery selection. Maybe I've misunderstood your question, because I don't understand what you expect `this` to be. Based on what I could understand from your question I thought you wanted bring the `this` from the code running `setInterval` into the `each` callback (as I said in my first sentence). Based on your code, however, that doesn't make any sense, because it seems you want to bring `window` into the `each` call, which breaks your code.

Comment: That said, your stand-alone call to `foo()` before `setInterval` may also be breaking things.